# jQuery section slider is not working in mobile device

Tags: jquery, mobile

The following code is not working in mobile. Can someone please help me on how to enable it on mobile?

Code: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/scrolling-sections-slider/

Comment: The plugin uses `wheel` event to detect scrolling. Mobile devices doesn't support this. Either you can try a different plugin or you'll have to modify the plugin and use touch events for mobile devices

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.